# Reporting Services: Subscription PDF generated Dundas Chart looks different from Preview Chart

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

Situation:

1. Running a report on SQL Server Reporting Services
2. When I do a Preview of the Report all my charts look fine. No problems.
3. When I run a subscription for the report, the chart look different. Like completely different legends are gone etc.

Any ideas what the cause would be?

BTW the charts are Dundas Charts.

Answer (score 0):

The format you are returning for the subscription is not the same as the preview (which is html). Try exporting from your preview to the format you are returning in your subscription. This should start to give you an idea what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

do you have code in your dundas objects that controls legends, etc?

if so, there is a bug with the dundas components that will prevent any of that code from executing when a report is run from an execution snapshot or subscription